# How to Assert StatusCode from raw POST request in my unit tests?

Tags: c#, moq, asp.net-core-webapi, xunit, http-status-codes

I am using **ASP.NET Core 2 WebAPI**, **xUnit**, **Moq**.

I have a problem. I was trying the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48264192/8532173) answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53083838/8532173) answer. Other found answers seem to be similar to these two.

With both mentioned approaches we are using casting of the `IActionResult result` object to `ObjectResult` or `OkObjectResult`.

The main problem with my project is that after casting object result is `null`.

Test method:

```
[Fact]
        public async Task Post_CalledWithDefaultSetup_CallsAllMethods()
        {
            //default setup arranged in the ctor

            IActionResult result = await _controller.Post();
            var okResult = result as ObjectResult;

            Assert.Equal(StatusCodes.Status200OK, okResult.StatusCode);
        }
```

`result` object on debug:
[image: result]

And tested method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
        {
            //do some logic here
            return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.OK); //debug hits this
        }
```

Also in my test class `ctor` I am arranging my mocks and ControllerContext:

```
_serializationServiceMock.Setup(s => s.UnzipData(_array))
                .Returns(_jsonExample);
            _serializationServiceMock.Setup(s => s.DeserializeDataFromJson(_jsonExample))
                .Returns(_listPersonModel);

            var stream = new MemoryStream(_array);
            var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
            httpContext.Request.Body = stream;
            httpContext.Request.ContentLength = stream.Length;
            var controllerContext = new ControllerContext()
            {
                HttpContext = httpContext,
            };
            _controller = new DataController(_repositoryMock.Object, _serializationServiceMock.Object) { ControllerContext = controllerContext };
```

Comment: `StatusCodeResult`, is not an `ObjectResult`, so you can't cast to that. The behavior of the `as` keyword is to return null when a cast is invalid. Testing a controller action is inherently an integration test, not a unit test. Use the test server and make an actual request to it, instead of trying to mock all the dependencies.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I mocked all services that the controller uses, also I faked `ControllerContext` passed with raw request, so the controller is completly isolated, I belive that there is no need to use integration. I just wanted to test logic inside when returns `Ok` or `BadRequest`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, are you saying that you can't unit test a controller method? I mean is it meaningless when you mock all dependencies? Even if I try to unit test filters?

Comment: It's not that you *can't*, but it's basically pointless to. There's so much involved (sessions, auth, filters, routing, model binding, etc.) that you will pretty much invariably have more test code than the actual code in the action. The test itself, then, is dependent on everything being mocked just right, so you basically have no idea whether your test fails because there's actually a problem or there's something wrong with your test code. That's a bad test.

Comment: Your actions should actually be very minimal. If there's any real work being done, that code should ideally be in a service method that the action simply calls. Then, you can unit test the service, and just integration test the action to ensure that it works end to end.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, Thank you for the clarification. Happy coding!

Comment: Personally I dont think that it took me too much effort to mock all dependencies and setup controller for unit testing of the api controller. But there is a chance that I did something wrong... ? https://github.com/przemyslawbak/Serializer/blob/9cbdae9a069d3b234a102af7f331b79a1409e813/Serializer.Tests/Web_API/DataControllerTests.cs#L49 basing on this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code block, the controller method returns `StatusCodeResult` type. But you try to cast it to `ObjectResult`. That's why you get null.

You can solve this in 2 ways;

**1 -)** You can use `return Ok()` instead of `return StatusCode(...)` so your controller method will return `OkResult` and with parametered call `Ok(someObj)` it will return `OkObjectResult`.

**2 -)** you can cast Post result to `StatusCodeResult` instead of `ObjectResult` since your endpoint returns status code result like below.

```cs
 var okResult = result as StatusCodeResult;
```

Comment: With `return Ok()`, `okResult` remains null. `result as StatusCodeResult` worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah my bad, `Ok()` return `OkResult` type without any parameter and returns `OkObjectResult ` when called like `return Ok(someObj);`. I am gonna update my answer

Comment: No problem. Anyway now I understand differences between `ObjectResult` and `StatusCodeResult`. Never worked with them before.